# For loops run SUPER slow in Julia when outside a function

Tags: for-loop, julia

There is a very peculiar slow down in Julia. When running, for example, a for loop by calling a function

```
function TestFunc(num)
     for i=1:num
     end
end
```

It is MUCH faster than when I just run a for loop for the exact same num ...

```
for i=1:num
end
```

The slow down isn't marginal either, it is magnitudes slower, the following image shows me running it.

[For Loop Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEpTZ.png)

In some of my other code, the opposite actually happens but I just feel like I am missing something fundamental about the way Julia runs. How do I keep my code optimal and why do these differences exist?

Comment: Read the performance tips. What you are seeing concerns the First Rule of Performance in Julia. https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot!

Comment: I can see this post getting plenty of visitors with v1.0 just released, so to expand on DNFs answer: Variables defined outside functions or modules exist in global scope. The Julia compiler cannot guarantee that variables in global scope will not have their type changed (unless they are declared `const`, which ensures fixed type but *not* fixed value). Therefore any code in global scope is slow unless you *really* know what you are doing. Takeaway: *Always* wrap your Julia routines in functions or modules. The first time you call them is slow (compile time), but subsequent calls are fast.

Comment: @ColinTBowers `const` does actually declare that the variable is constant (you will get a warning if you attempt to redefine a constant even if of the same type).

Comment: @SimonByrne You are correct. I was thinking of mutable types when I wrote my comment (e.g. you can add items to a `const Dict` without generating a warning), but admittedly, I also incorrectly thought it was fine to change the value of immutable constants. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @ColinTBowers So the concept you are referring to is `const Dict` ?

Comment: In my previous comment I was just making the point that any mutable type (e.g. `Dict`, `Array`, etc) can be declared constant with `const`, but you are still allowed to add or remove items from it (mutate it), as long as you don't change the type. Simon was just pointing out that this is *not* true of immutable types, e.g. `Float64`, `Int`, etc. If you try to change their value after declaring them `const`, you'll get a warning. This actually makes perfect sense, given that immutable types get re-allocated when you change their value.

Answer (score 5):

Anything you can write outside a function, you can write inside a function. So just like in C, you can write

```
function main()
    print("Hello World\n")
end

main()
```

So just pretend it is a C program and write your stuff inside the main() function.

Why is it so slow outside a function, it is because any variable inside a function is protected from being changed by another thread or task. So for a for loop in the global scope must check its variables for its type everytime it is access by the for loop, just in case it was change by another thread or task. All these checking is slowing it down FOR SAFETY.

The first Performance Law of Julia is

**Global is slow**

The performance tips in the Julia Documentation says

A global variable might have its value, and therefore its type, change at any point. This makes it difficult for the compiler to optimize code using global variables. Variables should be local, or passed as arguments to functions, whenever possible.

Any code that is performance critical or being benchmarked should be inside a function.